# Can't properly bind socket unless I pass a seemingly incorrect length

Tags: sockets, tcp, bind, ipv4

The code I've written doesn't work properly unless I pass a seemingly incorrect number to the length argument of `bind`. It kind of does work; after the `accept` call I can see it by running `netstat`, but the port is incorrect. I originally wrote the code in x86 assembly and I then wrote it in C. In both cases, it didn't work.

When calling the function `socket`, I passed `AF_INET` (2) as the domain, `SOCK_STREAM` (1) as the type, and TCP (6) as the protocol.

Here is the code, the one written in C:

```c
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    unsigned int fd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 6);
    struct sockaddr_in thing = (struct sockaddr_in) {
        .sin_family = AF_INET, //2 bytes
        .sin_port = 0x2923, //2 bytes
        .sin_addr = 0 //4 bytes
    };

    printf("%zu\n", sizeof thing);

    bind(fd, (struct sockaddr*) &thing, 8); //Using 16 instead of 8 fixes the port problem, why?
    listen(fd, 1);
    accept(fd, 0, 0);
}
```

To me, 8 looks like the correct length to use. However, 16 seems to be the correct number to use. Why?

Here is the original code written in x86 NASM Assembly:

```
section .text
global _start

_start:
    push byte 6
    push byte 1
    push byte 2
    mov ecx, esp
    mov ebx, 1              ;socket
    mov eax, 102
    int 80h

    mov edi, eax            ;file descriptor

    push dword 0x00000000   ;4 bytes
    push word 0x2923        ;2 bytes
    push word 2             ;2 bytes
    mov ecx, esp

    push byte 8             ;Length argument, byte turned into 4 bytes in stack
    push ecx
    push edi

    mov ecx, esp
    mov ebx, 2              ;bind
    mov eax, 102
    int 80h

    push byte 1
    push edi
    mov ecx, esp
    mov ebx, 4              ;listen
    mov eax, 102
    int 80h

    push byte 0
    push byte 0 

    push edi

    mov ecx, esp
    mov ebx, 5              ;accept
    mov eax, 102
    int 80h
```

Comment: Please refer to the definition of `struct sockaddr_in` on your specific platform - which is unknown. For example in Linux there is padding to make `sockaddr`_in and `sockaddr_in6` and `sockaddr` the same size.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich I use WSL. How could the padding affect the result when writing Assembly? What corresponds to the `addr` parameter clearly is 8 bytes in size. The only sensical explanation I can think of is `bind` adding 16 to the given address and then going backwards, with the padding being the first thing it encounters.

Comment: When running your code in Linux bind fails with EINVAL. But the code you show does not check for errors when calling bind and simply continues, thus essentially listening on a random port (implicit bind since the explicit bind failed). Don't know how this works in WSL, but I would be surprised if this is different.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ```
> bind(fd, (struct sockaddr*) &thing, 8); //Using 16 instead of 8 fixes the port problem, why?
> ```

This code will fail with EINVAL (checked with Linux), but this error is simply ignored by your program. This means no explicit `bind` will be done.

> ```
> listen(fd, 1);
> accept(fd, 0, 0);
> ```

Since the explicit `bind` failed an implicit `bind` will be done, effectively meaning that the socket will listen on a random address. That's why it does not seem to work. `netstat` should show the random port here, not the actually intended one.

Answer (score 2):

Look at the examples in the man page: https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/bind.2.html.

You have to pass the size of the sockaddr_in structure.

```
bind(fd, (struct sockaddr*) &thing, sizeof(thing));
```

It's very likely that `bind` makes an internal check, to ensure that the 3rd parameter is indeed the size of the structure in the 2nd parameter

For AF_INET sockets `bind` surely knows that the 2nd parameter is a `sockaddr_in` instance, so it **knows** what value the 3rd parameter must be.

Really, there's nothing mysterious going on here.

Comment: What I don't understand is why the size is 16 and not 8. I know that I can use `sizeof`, that's what I did with the printing part. Even if I didn't care about the answer of the question *why*, I still can't use `sizeof`, the original code I've written is in NASM assembly.

Comment: @Random It is because AF_UNIX and IPv6 also exist.